# Using Breakpoint on Visual Studio for minified JavaScript files with Source Map

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, bundling-and-minification, visual-studio-2015

I know source map files use to debug TypeScript files
I am trying to find a way to debug and use breakpoints on  Bundled and Minified (grunt-contrib-uglify) javascript files through Source Map in Visual Studio 2015
Chrome and IE11 allow me to show source map file to debug but I want to do this with Visual Studio to change/add Code in my Javascript file

do you know any technique allow me to use breakpoints on original files while minified versions are loaded in the browser
or should I write a HtmlHelper to load original Javascript files on Debugging like ScriptBundle does on VS 2013